# given a set of integers find if they can be added to a number

Tags: sql, sql-server, algorithm, math

We have numbers which are sum of these integers: [1, 2, 4]

For example 3(2+1), 6(4+2), 5(1+4), 7(1+2+4) Number from a list can only be used once. They can't be repeated.

Now I need to find all numbers, that are constructed like that, which includes 2 in their sum.

This is what I would write for this short list:

```
SELECT * FROM [TABLE] WHERE number = 2
OR number - 2 + 1 = 0  
OR number - 2 + 1 + 4 = 0
OR number - 2 + 4 = 0
```

But let's say we have 7 numbers in a list [1, 2, 4, 8, 16 ,72, 128]

So writing like that would be obviously too long and I'm failing to come up with some algorithm :(

I hope the problem is clear

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  Also I assume the numbers are not allowed to be repeated.

Comment: yes numbers are not repeating.

Comment: Is this your homework? Or a competition?

Comment: this is an intership task

Answer (score 1):

Would it be simply this?

```sql
SELECT * from [Table] WHERE number & 2 = 2
```

It is using the [bitwise AND](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/bitwise-and-transact-sql) to find numbers that have the 2-bit set.

**EDIT**
I am assuming that the list of numbers you use to create the sum (1,2,4,..) are all powers of 2. You can use these to add up to any (positive) number (provided the list is long enough), using each number 0 or 1 times.

Comment: what black magic is this? Works like a charm even for large numbers i've tried. Thank you :) not sure which one of you two answers I should accept, both impressive and super helpful..

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_number#Bitwise_operations

Comment: The task kind of reminds me of this http://www.mathmaniacs.org/lessons/01-binary/Magic_Trick/

Comment: @dave12345 . . . This doesn't work for your example with "72" in the list of numbers.

Comment: Yeah I think this answer assumes the power of two sequence continues after `[1, 2, 4]`. So 72 would be constructed from `64 + 8` can you clarify @dave12345

Comment: yes sequence continues. The full list I had to work with is: [0, 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 72, 128, 264, 512, 1024, 2048, 4096, 8192, 16384, 32768]

Comment: Hmm, they aren't all powers of 2 so either that list has an error or you will need to adjust this answer

Comment: Are you sure about that 72? I expect 32 and 64 instead

Comment: Yeah, that's how it's implemented in the app.. and @GordonLinoff how did you try to run with 72 to make this solution fail?

Comment: @dave12345 . . . I don't need to.  I understand the mathematics involved.

Comment: I think that if you limit yourself to testing for 1, 2 or 4, that 72 doesn't matter.

Comment: Having 72 in the list instead of 32 and 64 means that some values cannot be written as a sum of unique values from the list. Like any number between 32 and 71.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a recursive CTE:

```
with n as (
      select v.n
      from (values (1), (2), (4)) v(n)
     ),
     cte as (
      select n as num, n as max_n, convert(varchar(max), n) as calculation
      from n
      union all
      select num + n.n, n.n as max_n, concat(calculation, ' + ', n.n)
      from cte join
           n
           on n.n > cte.max_n
     )
select distinct num, calculation
from cte;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=44ee9117941bb04d70a534d56a31a81b) is a db<>fiddle.

This version also includes the calculation.  A number can appear multiple times if there are multiple ways of representing the number.

The above generates all combinations.  You can filter down to the ones that just have "2" after generating all of them.  Or you can handle "2" separately -- just generate all combinations without "2" and then add "2" to the final results.